# How to get current process in Linux-4.9 (and above) through registers in X86_64?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, x86-64

Since Linux 4.9 in X86, kernel changed the kernel stack by putting thread_info into task_struct and put current process into per_cpu section.
So it is NOT possible to get the current process in kernel through X86's SP register.
I am curious if there is still a way to get current process through CPU registers instead of using macro of get_current().

Comment: You can read the source to what `get_current()` does, or you can compile it to assembly and look at the output.

Comment: I believe in x86_64, the gsbase is set to point to the per-cpu data block, so the current task pointer will be at `%gs:NNN` for some constant offset NNN.  So fetching the pointer into `%rax` might look like `movq %gs:0x123, %rax`.

Comment: @NateEldredge your comment is correct. I did it as you said, and it worked.

Comment: A further question is how can I dump the memory from pointed by GS register? Is it possible to to this?